# Streaming to Twitch on Linux?

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, minecraft, streaming, video-streaming

One of my daughters wants to join the legions of people streaming to Twitch. However, we all have Ubuntu laptops. I've done some research and there seems to be a lot of discussion about it with possible soltuions. Since it doesn't seem to be a unique situation, have any of you made it work? Is it possible? Would I be better off having her run minecraft in virtualbox and doing it that way? Or maybe just do youtube? I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Minecraft, it is far better to stream using the built-in Twitch streamer. You can find settings for this by going into the Streaming settings by entering the Pause menu and selecting the Options menu. In this, you will see a `Streaming Settings` button. Click that.

Also note that you need to link your Mojang account to your Twitch account by going to their web site.

Also, most importantly, don't steal my subs!

Comment: Minecraft's built-in Twitch streaming only works on Windows. Twitch's library does not have Linux natives.

Comment: @smbarbour I've used streaming in Linux.

Comment: This is an excerpt from the version spec for the latest Minecraft (v 1.8.1): https://gist.github.com/smbarbour/144a1a91e37f7365f468
See also https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/1374789-twitch-integration-in-minecraft: "Windows 7 (32 or 64-bit) or Mac OS X 10.8 (64-bit only) or newer. Linux is not currently supported."

Answer (score 1):

OBS-studio is slowly getting usable on Linux, but only if you have Nvidia graphics.  I'm not sure about the Optimus graphics that typically inhabit laptops.

Another option is Simple Screen Recorder.  It requires some finagling in Pulseaudio to have both game audio and voice on the stream, but it can be fairly well automated with a shell script.

Laptops are also going to be hard-pressed to stream, whether in Linux or Windows.  Don't expect an i3 or i5 to handle it AT ALL.  A quad i7, MAYBE.  And I don't think AMD has anything in the laptop market that has that type of power.  This also applies to recording for YouTube.

Comment: Err...not true. We streamed Civ 5 to Twitchh just fine with an i5 (laptop, mind you) . No stutter, no nothing